# Graph Theory- show maximum number of edges in a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the maximum number of edges in a simple graph with ***n*** vertices is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer.

We have that is a simple graph, no parallel or loop exist. Therefore the degree of each vertex will be one less than the total number of vertices (at most).
ie,
   ***degree=n-1***

eg. we have a graph with two vertices (so one edge) degree=***(n-1***).

***(n-1)=(2-1)=1***

We know that the sum of the degree in a simple graph always even
ie, ***$\sum d(v)=2E$***

here ***d(v)=n-1***  : we have ***n*** vertices the total degree is ***n(n-1)***

***n(n-1)=2E***

***E=$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$***

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

HINT (?): Draw it. Each $n$ must be connected to all other $n's$. You will also use double-counting.